# Matching empty string is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, case

I have the following query

```
SELECT Ice.IceId, Ice.Code, Box.Ice, LEN(Box.Ice) AS IceCharLength,
       DATALENGTH(Box.Ice) AS DataLength, Box.Ice, ASCII(Box.Ice) AS ASCII, 
       CAST(Box.ice AS VARBINARY) AS VarBinary
FROM dbo.tblESPShipBox Box
LEFT JOIN ReferenceManual.IceType Ice
       ON Ice.Code = CASE
                        WHEN Box.ICE IS NULL THEN 'N'
                        WHEN RTRIM(Box.ICE) = '' THEN 'N'
                        WHEN Box.Ice IN ('', ' ', '/') THEN 'N'
                        ELSE Box.ICE
                      END
WHERE BOX_SEQ_NUM = '000023' AND BOX_TYPE_ID = 0
```

It returns the following results:

```
IceId       Code Ice  IceCharLength DataLength  Ice  ASCII       VarBinary
----------- ---- ---- ------------- ----------- ---- ----------- -------------
2           N         0             1                32          0x20
NULL        NULL      1             1                0           0x00
```

The weird thing is that `Box.ICE` for the first row is ' ' (Single Space String).  The second row seems to be '' (No space string).  (The way I see this is by copying the cell out and pasting in into other text to see if it makes a space or not.)

The `Box.ICE` column is a `char(1)` so I don't really see how a '' (no space string) got in there.

But the weird part is that my case statement should still match on a '' (no space) char.  But clearly it does not.

**How can I figure out what is really in this field and make it match my case statement?**

Things I have tried:

• Used SSMSBoost to do a special char included copy of the cell into NotePad++ (with show all chars on).  I did this to make sure there are no unplayable unicode chars.

Comment: `0x00` is the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Comment: @MartinSmith and Vaccano: regarding "shouldn't it still match an empty string?", it doesn't only because it's `VARCHAR` data using a SQL Server Collation, probably `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. If you were using `NVARCHAR` or a Windows Collation it would match the empty string branch of the `CASE` statement. Run the following 3 queries to verify this behavior: `SELECT 1 WHERE CHAR(0x00) = '' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS; SELECT 2 WHERE CHAR(0x00) = '' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS; SELECT 3 WHERE NCHAR(0x00) = '' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;` They will return "1" and "3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query:

```
 SELECT ASCII(' ') AS [SingleSpaceString]
      , ASCII('') AS [NoSpaceString]
```

You will note the the Value for [SingleSpaceString] is '32', while [NoSpaceString] is NULL.

I'd suggest adding ASCII(Box.Ice) to your select statement to confirm that a true space is the value, vs. an odd character.

Comment: I updated the case statement to have `WHEN ASCII(Box.Ice) = 0 THEN 'N'` and that got the match I needed.  Still seems odd to me though.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding the CASE statement you have into your SELECT statement so that you're able to see what the JOIN is working with.  That might bring a few things to light for you.  Maybe change your THEN statements to THEN 'Then1', THEN 'Then2' and THEN 'Then3', and also your "ELSE Box.Ice" to : "ELSE 'ElseReached' and see if you can track it down and confirm which CASE is being reached.